# Find ascending triples in a list

Tags: algorithm, list

I encountered the problem in a programming interview and have no idea about it by now.

> A list whose length is n, the elements in it are all positive integers without order.
>   To find out all possible triples (a, b, c), that a < b < c, and a appears before b and b before c in the list.
>
> And analyse the time complexity of your algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is known that there are only a small set of triples (say k), then you may prefer to find all the triples by storing pointers to the previous smallest element.

### ALGORITHM

Prepare an empty data structure (possible choices described later).

Prepare an empty array B of length n.

Then for each element c in the list:

1. Store the index (in the array B) of the most recent element in the list that is smaller than c (if it exists) using the data structure.
2. Store c (and its index in the original list) in the data structure
3. Then use array B to find all elements b smaller than c, and then again to find all elements a smaller than b, and emit all these combinations as output triples.

### DATA STRUCTURE

The data structure needs to be able to store value,position pairs to make it easy to find the largest position (i.e. most recent) over all elements with value less than c.

One easy way to do this if the range of allowed values is fairly small is to use a series of arrays where A[k][x] stores the maximum position for all elements in the range [x*2^k,(x+1)*2^k).

If the values have up to M bits (i.e. the values are in the range 0 to 2^M-1) then updating or accessing this data structure are both O(M) operations.

### COMPLEXITY

The given method is O(nM+k).

If the values have a larger range, then you could use a form of binary search tree instead of the series of arrays, or instead sort the values and replace the values with their ordinal value.  This would then have complexity O(nlogn+k).

### COUNTING TRIPLES

If you just wish to know the total number of triples of this form then you can do this in O(n).

The idea is similar to before:

1. Find the most recent smaller element for each index, and the count of smaller elements for each index
2. Find the next greater element for each index, and the count of greater elements
3. Compute the sum of the product of the count of smaller elements and the count of larger elements for each index.

To make this O(n) we need to be able to find the next greater element in O(n).  This can be done by:

1. Push the current index i to the stack
2. while A[top(stack)] < A[i+1], pop an index x off the stack and store NGE[x]=i+1
3. increment i and return to step 1

We also need to be able to find the count of greater elements in O(n).  Once the NGE array has been prepared, we can find the counts by iterating backwards over the array and computing

```
count_greater_elements[i] = count_greater_elements[ NGE[i] ] + 1 if NGE[i] is defined
                          = 0 otherwise
```

The most recent smaller elements and counts can be computed in an analogous way.

Comment: A case where there is a small set of triples is quite contrived.  If you reversed such an input for example it would turn it immediately into an input with a large number of triples.

Answer (score 4):

No general algorithm can be faster than O(n^3), as given a sorted input of distinct elements then the output will have size O(n^3), so just to produce the output will take time proportional.  Indeed even a randomly generated list of integers will already have n^3 triples up until constant factors.

That given you could simply iterate over all possible triples in list order, and compare them for sorted order.  This naive solution is already the best it can be asymptotically (that is O(n^3))

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
            if (X[i] < X[j] && X[j] < X[k)
                output(X[i],X[j],X[k])
```

I suspect you may have a transcription error in your problem statement - or else the question is supposed to be a very easy short coding exercise.

Comment: Test X[J]>X[i] before entering loop (k): it doesn't change the complexity, but it will improve performance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it isn't (conceptually) complicated to enumerate the outputs in O(nlogn + |L|) time where there are |L| outputs, and count them in O(nlogn) time. Whether you consider this faster than O(n³) is up to you -- I'd guess that on average there would be O(n³) triples anyway.

Comment: In both the average and worst case the number of triples is approximately n^3 up until constant factors - so this doesn't help or change anything.  Yes there is certainly a way to only count the number of triples faster, but this was not the problem statement, it asked to find them.

Comment: I'm just wondering how you know that there is no better solution? I don't follow your reasoning where you say the size O(n^3) implies that the time can't be less than O(n^3)

Comment: @sashang: In order to find n things, it must take at least O(n) time.  At a minimum the CPU needs to be in a state that corresponds to each one it finds. Say the shortest of these states are k nsecs, therefore a lower bound on the running time is kn nsecs, which is at least O(n) up until constant factors.

Answer (score 2):

N^2 solution for general case (to count all such triples, not output them all; output will take n^3 just because of its size):

for each number X in array lets count amount of numbers less than X with indexes less than x and amount of numbers greater than X with indexes greater than X. Than for each X we can get number of triples in which X is the middle element just as less[X] * greater[X]. The answer is sum of such products.

```
int calc(vector<int> numbers) {
 int n = numbers.size();
 vector<int> less(n), more(n);
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
   if (numbers[i] < numbers[j])
    less[j]++, more[i]++;

 int res = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  res += less[i] * more[i];

 return res;
}
```

Comment: The problem asks to find them, not count them.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I mentioned that on the first line in my answer. As far there is no faster than n^3 solution I guess my solution to similar problem can be helpful.